# Setting a fixed color scale for a series of data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been searching for a while, and I've found a number of answers for problems similar to mine, but not quite working when I try to implement them.

I'm trying to make a series of radar plots for different observations of performance. The data has been normalized such that the mean is 0 and the standard deviation is 1, and the y-axis on the plot has been set from -3 to 3 so as to make it visually comparable how well the subjects performed, with more extreme observations being worse. I would like to add colors associated with that scale, preferably such that -1 to 1 is green, and then the bands between +/- 1-2 is yellow and +/- 2-3 is red. All the examples I've been able to find relating to color fills is based directly in the data or from factors rather than a fixed scale, and anything I try seems to not show correctly. I'm not even sure if it is normally in the functionality of ggplot to be able to set a color scale in the way I'm looking for...

Here's the toy data I've been working with while working out the plotting (after reshaping):

```
variable <- c("time", "distance", "turns")
value <- c(0.9536197, 0.5842319, -2.1814528)
df <- data.frame(variable, value)
```

and here's my most recent attempt as far as ggplot code goes (using ggiraphExtra):

```
ggplot(temp, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_polygon() + 
  ggiraphExtra:::coord_radar() + ylim(-3,3) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green")
```

and this is the output: 
[radar plot with solid green geom_polygon fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdBRj.png)

Comment: One idea would be to create a classification variable and then use `scale_fill_discrete`

Comment: Trying to understand what you mean.. Are you looking for something other than a single fill color in your polygon? Since there are varying values in your sample data. (Btw I assume `df` & `temp` refers to the same data?)

Comment: @Z.Lin Yes, I was hoping for a gradient fill or something to make the location of the score on the axis clearer...after some digging, it looks like gradients in polygons are a bit difficult, so I think I'll find a different solution..possibly just work with gradients on the points themselves. And yes df and temp are the same--I missed that when copying the code over, sorry :x